# Is there a way to format tables by applying text wrap down and setting the column size in xls using tablib library of python

Tags: python, excel, tablib

I used python library `tablib v0.10.0`. I have a document which has a column with each row containing large amount of text. But after I generated the document I found that it is not as beautified or formatted as I want it to be. I basically want to increase the column size and apply text wrap down to the entire sheet of the Dataset.

```
tab_data = tablib.Dataset(*dataList, headers=headers_list, title="Sample sheet")
```

Is there a way for me to set column size while initializing the Dataset in the above step?

Comment: According to the (User’s Guide)[http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/] there is no Formatting Supported. Other `xlsx` Packages e.g. `OpenPyXL` are able to do so.